# Creating a Tab Delimited Text File Manually in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, unicode

I am trying to create tab delimited text file using vba in Access. This file is essentially reading data from tables and has a few bits of strings of text at the start of the file. The purpose of this is to create a Shared Parameter text file that can be read in another software (Autodesk Revit)

The problem I am having is what I export doesn't seem be a tab delimited file. I can test this by trying to import this into excel and it does not recognize it as a tab delimited file.

The snippet below shows what I have coded up. Running it and then trying to import in Excel, shows that it is not read as a tab delimited file. For convenience I have commented out sections that read the database as it is not relevant to the actual problem.

```
Public Function ExportRevitSharedParameterFile()

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Dim header As String
    Dim metaHeader As String
    Dim groupHeader As String
    Dim paramHeader As String

    Dim metaData As String
    Dim groupData As String
    Dim paramData As String

    header = "# This is a Revit shared parameter file." & vbCrLf & "# Do not edit manually."
    metaHeader = "*META" & vbTab & "VERSION" & vbTab & "MINVERSION"
    groupHeader = "*GROUP" & vbTab & "ID" & vbTab & "NAME"
    paramHeader = "*PARAM" & vbTab & "GUID" & vbTab & "NAME" & vbTab & "DATATYPE" & vbTab & "DATACATEGORY" & vbTab & "GROUP" & vbTab & "VISIBLE" & vbTab & "DESCRIPTION" & vbTab & "USERMODIFIABLE"

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' This path may need to be changed to an appropriate location with permission access
    Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\sp.txt", True, True)

    a.WriteLine (header)
    a.WriteLine (metaHeader)

    metaData = "META" & vbTab & "2" & vbTab & "1"
    a.WriteLine (metaData)

    a.WriteLine (groupHeader)
    'Write some data from an access table
    'Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SP File - Groups", dbOpenSnapshot)
    'Do While Not rst.EOF
    '    groupData = "GROUP" & vbTab & rst![Group ID] & vbTab & rst![Group Name]
    '    a.WriteLine (groupData)
    '    rst.MoveNext
    'Loop
    'rst.Close
    'Set rst = Nothing

    a.WriteLine (paramHeader)
    'Write some data from an access table
    'Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SP File - Parameters", dbOpenSnapshot)
    'Do While Not rst.EOF
    '    paramData = "PARAM" & vbTab & rst![Parameter GUID] & vbTab & rst!Name & vbTab & rst![Revit Type] & vbTab & "" & vbTab & rst![Group ID] & vbTab & "1" & vbTab & "" & vbTab & "1"
    '    a.WriteLine (paramData)
    '    rst.MoveNext
    'Loop
    'rst.Close
    'Set rst = Nothing

    a.Close

End Function
```

Any help on this will be appreciated. I am obviously missing some info on how tab delimited files are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "regular" Tab separated values (TSV) file looks like this, with a constant number of columns:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
| Data | Data | Data |
| Data | Data | Data |
+------+------+------+
```

Your file starts with two lines that don't have TABs in them:

```
header = "# This is a Revit shared parameter file." & vbCrLf & "# Do not edit manually."
```

When determining the structure of a text file, Excel looks at the first few lines (5 or 10, I think), and at the extension. In your case, the file is recognized as "plain text".

In order to make Excel recognize your file as TSV, try this:

- Remove the first two lines

and/or

- Rename it from `.txt` to `.tsv`

Excel may still not like the fact that you have different blocks (META / GROUP / PARAM) with different number of columns.

But the real test is of course: does the target software (Autodesk) work with the file?

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful in understanding why I was getting it to work with excel in certain cases depending on what I exported to the file. It wasn't working in the software initially. However thanks to your explanation above I started to look more closely at what the file should read and found an error. Cheers